# makefile linking does not work (although no error message)

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, linker

I am having issue with Makefile that I produced. It consists of one .cpp file with main() inside and I want to create executable from it. While putting in terminal **make** command I get following:

```
g++ STutorial.o -o MyExecutable
g++: error: STutorial.o: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
```

While putting first **make STutorial.o** (.o created) and then **make** get this:

```
g++ STutorial.o -o MyExecutable
STutorial.o: In function `main':
STutorial.cpp:(.text+0x47a): undefined reference to `alcOpenDevice'
```

Firstly, why **make** does not go from the beginning?
Secondly, why this reference is undefined as if I did not include library, I did that in Makefile aswell as in STutorial.cpp file.
Can you please help me out? I was reading up what could I do wrong and see no clue. (I am beginner and maybe mistake is a rookie one, I apologise in advance but cannot understand it alone)
Makefile:

```
FLAGS += -std=c++11
CCX=g++
FLAGS +=-c -Wall #for compilation, for warning
FLAGS += -lopenal -lSDL
all: MyExecutable
MyExecutable:
    $(CXX) STutorial.o -o MyExecutable
STutorial.o: STutorial.cpp
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) STutorial.cpp
```

Comment: What is the question? I see you are asking for help but perhaps structuring your question to identify the task you are trying to solve, highlight what you have tried, and then ask for help to overcome a specific issue, would help get you better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problem in your Makefile starting with:

```
FLAGS +=-c -Wall #for compilation, for warning
FLAGS += -lopenal -lSDL
```

You are redefining the FLAGS variable here.
So what you should have is a different variable for your compiler and linker flags:

```
CFLAGS +=-c -Wall #for compilation, for warning
LDFLAGS += -lopenal -lSDL
```

Now, for the sake of giving a complete answer, and not solving your immediate problem only I'll try to show how to make the Makefile more flexible:

1. Start with the sources - you should have a variable for them as well; it's useful when adding/removing source files to/from the project:

   ```
   SOURCES = STutorial.cpp
   ```
2. define a variable for your object files (this will come in handy at link-time):

   ```
   OBJ = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
   ```
3. Compile all source files into object files:

   ```
   .cpp.o:
       $(C++) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
   ```
4. Link your binary file using the compiled object files:

   ```
   $(MyExecutable): $(OBJ)
      $(C++) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $@
   ```
5. Add a clean command for completeness (removes the binary and object files):

   ```
   clean:
       $(RM) $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJ)
   ```

Now, putting it all together:

```
CCX=g++
CFLAGS +=-c -Wall -std=c++11#for compilation, for warning
LDFLAGS += -lopenal -lSDL
SOURCES = STutorial.cpp

OBJ = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(MyExecutable)

$(MyExecutable): $(OBJ)
       $(CCX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $@ 

.cpp.o:
        $(CCx) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

 clean:
        $(RM) $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJ)
```

This should allow you to flexibly build, rebuild, clean you project.

Comment: You should clean up some of these rules, there's a lot of mistyping.

Answer (score 3):

Your makefile should be like this:

```
CCX=g++
FLAGS +=-c -Wall #for compilation, for warning
LINK_FLAGS += -lopenal -lSDL
all: MyExecutable
MyExecutable: Stutorial.o
    $(CXX) STutorial.o -o MyExecutable $(LINK_FLAGS) 
STutorial.o: STutorial.cpp
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) STutorial.cpp
```

Explanation:

Your `MyExecutable` depends on `Stutorial.o` which inturn depends on `Stutorial.cpp`

Now `-c` flag should be used only with `.cpp` file to create an object file and not with already created `.o` file.

Therefore you should have two flags: `FLAGS` for compiling and `LINK_FLAGS` for linking libraries during making executable file.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, clear for me now. While applying your solution I get the undefined reference error. But while typing in console g++ STutorial.cpp -lopenal -lSDL, everything is fine! How is that possible (last one creates me a.out but I want to have influence on name and understand way it works, too.)

Comment: Try putting `$(LINK_FLAGS)` after `MyExecutable` in the makefile.

Comment: It's also a good practice to use the Library location flag `-L` before your library name otherwise compiler will not be able to find your library.

Comment: error (at line with $(LINK_FLAGS)) : missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: problem solved, unseen whitespaces left that crooked the intendations

Answer (score 2):

Your executable rule is the issue:

```
MyExecutable:
    $(CXX) STutorial.o -o MyExecutable
```

It has a target (`MyExecutable`) and it has a recipe `($(CXX) ...)`, that all looks good. But what are its prerequisites? `MyExecutable` *does* have prerequisites - it needs `STutorial.o` in order to generate the binary! You need to explicitly tell make about this:

```
MyExecutable: STutorial.o
    $(CXX) STutorial.o -o MyExecutable
```

Otherwise, you are telling make that you want to build `all`. `all` depends on `MyExecutable`. `MyExecutable` doesn't depend on anything, so the rule for `STutorial.o` never gets run.

As for the linker error, you're not linking in the library you need, so you should define something like:

```
LFLAGS += -lopenal -lSDL

MyExecutable: STutorial.o
    $(CXX) STutorial.o $(LFLAGS) -o MyExecutable
```

Comment: i created makefile as from bavesh advice above. I get the linker error still. However, when simply typing **g++ STutorial.cpp -lopenal -lSDL**, it gives no error. Where is the difference?

Comment: @beginh You didn't provide the `-lopenal -lSDL` flags to g++ when you are compiling your binary. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! for those tracking the discussion: put the libraries for linking in the proper place so after objects and before -o

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall  -lopenal -lSDL STutorial.cpp -o MyExecutable
```

Comment: But that created MyExecutable as an object, not executable file. Can you please explain?

Comment: remove `-c` flag and it will be executable.